# Trying to make a button in Unity which spawns a character each time it's clicked

Tags: unity, c#

I have a simple 2D game, I want a UI button to respawn the character (if it's not already present). The first problem I encountered is that the button only works once. I can't go any further before I solve this, so for now it doesn't spawn anything, I just want it to print debug text every time it's clicked.
It only does that once, unfortunately. How do I make it call the function each time I click it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Button_Restart : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas Canvas;

    void Awake()
    {

    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        Debug.Log("Restart button was clicked");
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was silly and didn't notice that the console was set to group debug messages together. It is in fact working as intended.